# How can two DataFrames on specific columns be merged but only keeping the rows from the first DataFrame if they appear in the second?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Here is an example of my problem:

### Data A

```
  fname lname  age company
0  Logi     G   24      SV
1  Gary     J   25     IBT
```

### Data B

```
  fname lname  age   company
0  Logi     G   24        SV
1  Gary     J   25        IV
2  Adam     B   26  Johnston
```

I want to end up with

```
  fname lname  age   company
0  Logi     G   24        SV
1  Gary     J   25        IBT
2  Adam     B   26  Johnston
```

Where row 1 of the merged dataframe is from **Data A**

```
merge_d = pd.merge(data_a,data_b, how='outer', on=['fname', 'lname', 'age', 'company'])
```

This is the query I used however I end up with

```
  fname lname  age   company
0  Logi     G   24        SV
1  Gary     J   25       IBT
2  Gary     J   25        IV
3  Adam     B   26  Johnston
```

Comment: Your dataset B and output are the same

Comment: In the output row 1 from dataset B appears with index 2

Comment: What you are looking for is A plus Outer Right of B

Comment: Yes thats it, so may be I should get the outer right of B and then append to A?

Comment: Yes, thats what I would do. I posted an answer, on how I would go about it, does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does that work?

```
df = pd.merge(data_a, data_b, on=['fname', 'lname', 'age'], how="outer", indicator=True)
df = df[df['_merge'] == 'right_only']
output = pd.concat([data_a, df])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
result = data_a.merge(data_b, how='outer', on=['fname', 'lname', 'age'],
    suffixes=['', '_y'])
result.company.update(result.company_y)
result.drop(columns=['company_y'], inplace=True)
```

The result is:

```
  fname lname  age   company
0  Logi     G   24        SV
1  Gary     J   25        IV
2  Adam     B   26  Johnston
```

## If you have more non-key columns

If you have more columns (besides your 3 join columns), *merge* will
result in other respective columns, with *_y* suffix.

Then run additional *update* for these columns and then drop all these
*_y* columns.

E.g. if you have another *email* column, then after *merge* run:

```
result.email.update(result.email_y)    # Additional instruction
# Extend the list of columns to drop
result.drop(columns=['company_y', 'email_y'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: This seems very useful how can you do this with multiple columns for example maybe company and email?